# AS3 JSON parsing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, json

I have a bit of a dilemma. I have a JSON object that has a format I'm unfamiliar with (starts with an array `[]` instead of an object `{}`) and was wondering how I  might parse it in AS3. The object looks like:

```
[
    {
        "food": [
            {
                "name": "pasta",
                "price": 14.50,
                "quantity": 20
            },
            {
                "name": "soup",
                "price": 6.50,
                "quantity": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "food": [
            {
                "name": "salad",
                "price": 2.50,
                "quantity": 3
            },
            {
                "name": "pizza",
                "price": 4.50,
                "quantity": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I don't really know how I get to each food array, and each object within it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

from flash player 11, and sdk 4.6 there is native support for json. To use it you should change

```
var foods:Array = JSON.decode(jsonstring);
```

to

```
var foods:Array = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
```

while JSON is not from as3corelib but from sdk itself. Pretty much faster ;)

Comment: The only thing that needs to be changed is that `var foods:Array` should be changed to `var foods:Object`. When I tried with Array it said the type was not valid for what JSON.parse returns.

Comment: "Access of undefined property JSON."

Comment: i'm using sdk 4.5, i have this JSON class too

Answer (score 12):

You will need to use the JSON Object Class (below link)
http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/

and then something like this..

```
var data:String = "{\"name\":\"pizza\",\"price\":\"4.50\",\"quantity\":\"2\"}";
var food:JSONObject = new JSONObject(data);
trace(food.name); // Pizza
trace(food.price); // 4.50
trace(food.quantity); // 2
food.number++;
var newData:String = String(food);
trace(newData); // {"name":"pizza","price":"4.50","quantity":"2"}
```

Comment: i've tried using that method, however with the json i posted above, do i need to start with a JSONArray first, and then a JSON object? since it is wrapped first by [] and then by {}.

Comment: +1 AS3corelib is good. @dtrainer45: if you use adobe flexbuilder, add a breakpoint after deserializing the json string. Then you can explore the structure of the created object graph. If it is an array, it should probably be something like var x:JSONObject = new JSONObject(data); trace(x[0].food[0].name); not tested though.

Answer (score 7):

Interesting datastructure... this should do it:

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
/* ... other code ... */
var foods:Array = JSON.decode(jsonstring);
for(var i:int = 0; i < foods.length; i++) {
  for(var j:int = 0; j < foods[i].length; j++) {
    trace(foods[i][j].name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for an alternative to a library and found the technique [here](http://blog.kreatx.com/2011/10/24/better-actionscript-json-encodedecode/).  I'm assuming this will work in the context of the op (which was answered years ago of course) since it doesn't require a return type of Object. This works well for what I was trying to do when I found this post and I found the solution pretty elegant for flash based in the browser.

```
function json_decode( data:String ):* {
  try {
    return ExternalInterface.call("function(){return " + data + "}");
  } catch (e:Error) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: **Note:** As is, this a big security vulnerability. It would be better to use: `ExternalInterface.call("function(){return JSON.decode('" + data.replace(/(['\\])/g, "\\$1"); + "');}")`

Comment: @brianreavis: just `ExternalInterface.call('JSON.parse', data)` should do it :-)

Comment: noted, thanks!  At the time I just needed to get something working and I was in control of the data source.  As an aside, this will not work with IE7 and lower due to lack of a native JSON api as per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908875/is-json-parse-supported-by-all-major-browsers