# JSON object undefined in IE compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var markers = JSON.parse('[{"title":"Chennai","lat":"12.897400","lng":"80.288000","Description":"welcome to chennai"},{"title":"Hyderabad","lat":"17.266700","lng":"78.530200","Description":"welcome to hyderabad"},{"title":"Banglore","lat":"12.897400","lng":"77.519500","Description":"welcome to Banglore"},{"title":"vishkapatnam","lat":"17.518300","lng":"83.320300","Description":"welcome to Vishkapatnam"}]');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        };
```

I am getting the JSON is not find Microsoft?so what do i do?

Comment: Which version of IE(I suppose) are you using?

Comment: That's very strange, in IE8 it should be already fully supported, anyway read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908875/is-json-parse-supported-by-all-major-browsers

Comment: Almost certain to be caused by IE8 in compatibility mode (or quirks mode).

Comment: I arranged IE8 compatibility mode but it show as same as

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if you are in compatibility mode.
You can ensure that IE8 is not rendering in IE7 mode via a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
```

or preferably, using the doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere before your code :

```
window.JSON || 
    document.write('<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.2.4/json3.min.js"><\/script>');
```

Comment: but it shows same as sir

Comment: what give alert(typeof window.JSON); ?

Comment: JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>');

Comment: window.JSON ||
    document.write('<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.2.4/json3.min.js"><\/script>');

Comment: give me the link of your project please..