# How can I get json data to an array in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I want to get this json to an array.

```
data='{"Status":200,"Method":"SelectCompany","Errors":[],"Data":[{"Name":"MoreTimeAPITest","OrgNumber":"1234561234","APIKey":"168080BF-77A9-4B64-94C3-A5B3B4512A1C","Login":"moretime","Password":"SvMrqwk4G3"}],"DataType":{"Type":"list","ObjectType":"APIConnections"},"ResponseType":"json","API_Version":"1","API_Name":"PromikBook API","Server_Time":"2014-02-13 13:39:56.62275"}';

var newArr = [];
```

I used this code. But it is not working.

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
     console.log([obj.Status]);

    newArr.push([obj.Status]);
});
```

Comment: data is a string not an object

Comment: @user...you need to parse the json

Comment: It is not clear what you want the result to be.  The data you show in your question only has one `Status` property in the entire object so it's unclear what you want in an array.

Comment: I want to show this json data on a table. So how Can I do it?

Comment: Show what you want the HTML to look like that you want to generate from this JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn the JSON string into a JavaScript Object using JSON.parse.  Note that older browsers don't support JSON.parse (see [this Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/json) and [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908875/is-json-parse-supported-by-all-major-browsers)).

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"Status":200,"Method":"SelectCompany","Errors":[],"Data":[{"Name":"MoreTimeAPITest","OrgNumber":"1234561234","APIKey":"168080BF-77A9-4B64-94C3-A5B3B4512A1C","Login":"moretime","Password":"SvMrqwk4G3"}],"DataType":{"Type":"list","ObjectType":"APIConnections"},"ResponseType":"json","API_Version":"1","API_Name":"PromikBook API","Server_Time":"2014-02-13 13:39:56.62275"}');

$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
    console.log([obj.Status]);

    newArr.push([obj.Status]);
});
```